# Width and alignment of captions inside tcolorboxes/parboxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, width

I am using tcolorbox for boxes containing a theorem. They are divided into two halves: on the left text and equations, on the right a picture. How can I achieve **both**

- fit the caption text to (halft the) box width i. e. to fit below the image (my caption is always rendered as a too wide single line)

**and**

- left-align the caption text

?

I only manage to achieve one of the above

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % Frames
\usepackage{caption} % Frames
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = part]
{The}{Satz}{%
breakable
}{the}


\begin{document}

\begin{The}{Satz des Pythagoras}{FKT-Pythagoras}
\parbox{0.5    \textwidth}{
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2.
\]
}     \parbox{0.5    \textwidth}{
%Bild_TrigoPolyGrad1
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=0.5    \textwidth]{../../Bausteine/FKT/Bilder/FKT_pythagoras.png}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=newline}       
    \caption[]{Satz des Pythagoras im rechtwinkligen Dreieck.}
        \label{fig:FKT-pythagoras2}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{The}

\begin{The}{Satz des Pythagoras}{FKT-Pythagoras}
\parbox{0.5    \textwidth}{
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2.
\]
}     \parbox{0.5    \textwidth}{
%Bild_TrigoPolyGrad1
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=0.5    \textwidth]{../../Bausteine/FKT/Bilder/FKT_pythagoras.png}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=newline,width=0.25    \textwidth}      
    \caption[]{Satz des Pythagoras im rechtwinkligen Dreieck.}
        \label{fig:FKT-pythagoras}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{The}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `figure` environment is for floating, but you do not want the figures to float, so use `center` instead and `\captonof{figure}{...}`.  Consider using `minipage`s instead of `\parbox`es too, since `minipages` are designed to hold vertical material.  Below I give examples of both uses.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = part]
{The}{Satz}{%
breakable
}{the}

\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=newline}
\begin{document}

\begin{The}{Satz des Pythagoras}{FKT-Pythagoras}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \[
      a^2+b^2=c^2.
    \]
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    % Bild_TrigoPolyGrad1
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../../Bausteine/FKT/Bilder/FKT_pythagoras.png}
      \captionof{figure}{Satz des Pythagoras im rechtwinkligen
      Dreieck.}
      \label{fig:FKT-pythagoras}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
\end{The}

\begin{The}{Satz des Pythagoras}{FKT-Pythagoras}
  \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
  \[
    a^2+b^2=c^2.
  \]
  }%
  \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
  % Bild_TrigoPolyGrad1
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{../../Bausteine/FKT/Bilder/FKT_pythagoras.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Satz des Pythagoras im rechtwinkligen Dreieck.}
    \label{fig:FKT-pythagoras2}
  \end{center}
  }
\end{The}


\end{document}
```